# Why won't R access all of the values in a certain row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I read a large (24,000 observations and 1900 variables) dataset into R using this command:

```
expression_data<-read.table("data_expression_median.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

When I look at my data using `view(expression_data)` and when I pull a limited number of rows/columns out with `expression_data[1:3,1:5]`, all of the data shows up correctly. Also, when I use the command `expression_data[3, 1:5]` it prints the column headers AND the actual values (which is the expected result):

```
  Hugo_Symbol Entrez_Gene_Id  MB.0362  MB.0346  MB.0386
3    CD049690             NA 5.453928 5.454185 5.501577
```

However, when I try to subset an entire row using `expression_data[3,]` or any other command to pull out an entire row, I only get the column headers:

```
Hugo_Symbol Entrez_Gene_Id MB.0362 MB.0346 MB.0386
     MB.0574 MB.0503 MB.0641 MB.0201 MB.0218 MB.0316 MB.0189
     MB.0891 MB.0658 MB.0899 MB.0605 MB.0258 MB.0506 MB.0420
     MB.0223 MB.0445 MB.0199 MB.0517 MB.0155 MB.0428 MB.0117
```

Why is this? What am I doing wrong? I need to do operations on a row basis so I need to be able to access the data from entire rows.

Comment: try `utils::View(expression_data[3,])`

Comment: @Wimpel that worked! It open a window and it seems like all the values are there. How can I access those values though?

Comment: R has printing limits and your data are very wide. `expression_data[3,]` has all the values and you can access them, they just won't be printed by default.

Comment: @GregorThomas Gotcha. I was confused because it wasn't allowing me to calculate the median of a row but it appears I just needed to use ```as.numeric``` Thank you!

Comment: For a data frame, `df[1, ]` is still a data frame, not a vector. If you're treating rows as vectors regularly, you may want to convert your data to a `matrix` for efficiency.

Comment: @GregorThomas, post as answer? (Or close as "not reproducible"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R has printing limits and your data are very wide. `expression_data[3,]` has all the values and you can access them, they just won't be printed by default.

You can play with the print options, especially the `max.print` option to get it to print more in your console, but the R console is really the wrong tool to view thousands of columns of data.

If you're doing a lot of math on the rows of a data frame, you may consider converting to `matrix` for efficiency.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!